# Notation for a map to undefined elements

Tags: notation, definition

I am trying to write the output of a universal Turing machine using the map notation. Let $L$ be the set of all sentences of the binary language. Then the map:

$$
\operatorname{UTM}: L \to L 
$$

and I implement the map as:

$$
\operatorname{UTM}[s]=\cases{r & If UTM[s] halts \\
\nexists & otherwise}
$$

where $s$ and $r$ are elements of $L$.

---

However, since $\nexists$ is not an element of $L$, the implementation is not allowed by the definition of the map. Note that the empty sentence $\varnothing \in L$ is not the same as $\nexists$.

---

Is there a standard way to define maps that can include $\nexists$ in the image? Otherwise, I would like to consider the pros and cons of these two possible fixes:

---

### 1. Define the map as:

$$
\operatorname{UTM}:L \to L \cup \{\nexists\} 
$$

In the case, the implementation can live within the definition. But it feels like its a loophole to the requirement that a map must map each element of its domain? Is it allowed?

### 2. Define the domain of $\operatorname{UTM}$ as a suitable subset of $L$

I define a subset of $L$ which only includes the sentences that halt for $\operatorname{UTM}$. We can call this subset the domain of the universal Turing machine: $\operatorname{Dom}(\operatorname{UTM}) \subset L$. Then the map is defined as:

$$
\operatorname{UTM}:\operatorname{Dom}[\operatorname{UTM}] \to L
$$

The implementation would simply be

$$
\operatorname{UTM}[s]=r
$$

But this feels odd because the complexity of the implementation is pushed into the definition of the map, leaving the implementation very simple and the definition relatively more complex.

Comment: I think both approaches are valid and well defined. To define a map in classic mathematics you don't need to actually know how to compute it.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just add a special element to $L$ called ☹, forming a new language $L'$? And then say "$\text{UTM}[☹] = ☹$; otherwise, for any binary string $s$, $UTM[s] = r$ if the UTM halts, and ☹ if it does not". So now it's a function from $L'$ to itself, with no worrying about partial functions.